# Google Foobar: Free the Bunny Prisoners clarification

Tags: java, python

I'm working my way through Google Foobar and I'm very confused about "Free the Bunny Prisoners".  I'm not looking for code, but I could use some insight from anyone that's completed it.  First, the problem:

> ## Free the Bunny Prisoners
>
> You need to free the bunny prisoners before Commander Lambda's space
>   station explodes! Unfortunately, the commander was very careful with
>   her highest-value prisoners - they're all held in separate,
>   maximum-security cells. The cells are opened by putting keys into each
>   console, then pressing the open button on each console simultaneously.
>   When the open button is pressed, each key opens its corresponding lock
>   on the cell. So, the union of the keys in all of the consoles must be
>   all of the keys. The scheme may require multiple copies of one key
>   given to different minions.
>
> The consoles are far enough apart that a separate minion is needed for
>   each one. Fortunately, you have already freed some bunnies to aid you
>   - and even better, you were able to steal the keys while you were working as Commander Lambda's assistant. The problem is, you don't
>   know which keys to use at which consoles. The consoles are programmed
>   to know which keys each minion had, to prevent someone from just
>   stealing all of the keys and using them blindly. There are signs by
>   the consoles saying how many minions had some keys for the set of
>   consoles. You suspect that Commander Lambda has a systematic way to
>   decide which keys to give to each minion such that they could use the
>   consoles.
>
> You need to figure out the scheme that Commander Lambda used to
>   distribute the keys. You know how many minions had keys, and how many
>   consoles are by each cell.  You know that Command Lambda wouldn't
>   issue more keys than necessary (beyond what the key distribution
>   scheme requires), and that you need as many bunnies with keys as there
>   are consoles to open the cell.
>
> Given the number of bunnies available and the number of locks required
>   to open a cell, write a function answer(num_buns, num_required) which
>   returns a specification of how to distribute the keys such that any
>   num_required bunnies can open the locks, but no group of (num_required
>   - 1) bunnies can.
>
> Each lock is numbered starting from 0. The keys are numbered the same
>   as the lock they open (so for a duplicate key, the number will repeat,
>   since it opens the same lock). For a given bunny, the keys they get is
>   represented as a sorted list of the numbers for the keys. To cover all
>   of the bunnies, the final answer is represented by a sorted list of
>   each individual bunny's list of keys.  Find the lexicographically
>   least such key distribution - that is, the first bunny should have
>   keys sequentially starting from 0.
>
> num_buns will always be between 1 and 9, and num_required will always
>   be between 0 and 9 (both inclusive).  For example, if you had 3
>   bunnies and required only 1 of them to open the cell, you would give
>   each bunny the same key such that any of the 3 of them would be able
>   to open it, like so: [   [0],   [0],   [0], ] If you had 2 bunnies and
>   required both of them to open the cell, they would receive different
>   keys (otherwise they wouldn't both actually be required), and your
>   answer would be as follows: [   [0],   [1], ] Finally, if you had 3
>   bunnies and required 2 of them to open the cell, then any 2 of the 3
>   bunnies should have all of the keys necessary to open the cell, but no
>   single bunny would be able to do it.  Thus, the answer would be: [
>   [0, 1],   [0, 2],   [1, 2], ]
>
> ## Languages
>
> To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py To provide a Java
>   solution, edit solution.java
>
> ## Test cases
>
> Inputs:
>       (int) num_buns = 2
>       (int) num_required = 1 Output:
>       (int) [[0], [0]]
>
> Inputs:
>       (int) num_buns = 5
>       (int) num_required = 3 Output:
>       (int) [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9], [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]]
>
> Inputs:
>       (int) num_buns = 4
>       (int) num_required = 4 Output:
>       (int) [[0], [1], [2], [3]]

I can't figure out why `answer(5, 3) = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9], [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]]`.  It seems to me that `[[0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [1], [2]]` completely satisfies the requirements laid out in the description.  I don't know why you'd ever have keys with a value greater than num_required-1.

One possibility I thought of was that there are unwritten rules that say all of the minions/bunnies need to have the same number of keys, and you can only have num_required of each key.  However, if that's the case, then `[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]` would be okay.

Next I thought that maybe the rule about needing to be able to use all num_required keys at once extended beyond 0, 1, and 2, regardless of how many consoles there are.  That is, you should be able to make `[6, 7, 8]` as well as `[0, 1, 2]`.  However, that requirement would be broken because the first bunny doesn't have any of those numbers.

I'm stuck.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed the part where it says

`but no group of (num_required - 1) bunnies can.`

I can explain my solution further, but I will ruin the fun. (I'm the owner of that repo).
Let's try it with your answer.

`[[0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [1], [2]]`

Your consoles are 3. Bunny 2 can open it on its own, Bunny 3 can open it also on his own -> it does NOT satisfy the rule.

Comment: Ahh!  Thank you so much!  I had a feeling I missed something in there.  It's kind of a strange rule though.  It also said the consoles are far enough apart that a separate minion is needed for each one, which would imply that n-1 bunnies couldn't physically do it, regardless of keys.  Oh well.  I'll just assume that bunnies have longer arms than minions.  ;)  Whatever the case, I'm so glad to have something more to go on.

Comment: [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,8,9],[0,1,6,7,8,9],[2,3,4,5,6,7],[4,5,6,7,8,9]]
Why this cannot be a possible solution?

Comment: Based on this, surely:
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9], [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]]
is not a valid solution, since bunny 0 can open it on its own, as can bunny 1, as can many other combinations of only 2 bunnies

Comment: but then can't bunny 0 & bunny 1 in `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9], [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]]` this sample testcase open it as it has 0, 1 & 2?